# SQL: How to extract a check on these values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having troubling extracting some data from a certain (strangely built) table. What I want to do is extract value X from these values, to ensure the value exists:

```
Name        | Fieldinfo | ValueDateTime | X

Date        | NULL      | 2017-07-05    | 1

AmountGross | 123.45    | NULL          |1

AmountNet   |  137.02   | NULL          | 1

AmountVat   | 28.77     | NULL          | 1
```

I'm asware the database is weird, as these are all records, but I want to extract the value from it. I tried doing:

```
SELECT tel from (select count(X) as tel
from headfields where Fieldinfo in ('123.45', '137.02', '28.77')  
UNION 
 select Xfrom headfields where ValueDateTime = '2017-07-05' ) as tel
```

But this returns all the records that have the values, indeependent of the UNION.

Comment: can you please share your expected output

Comment: I want to receive the X where all these values match, so:
When AmountGross = 123,45, AmountNet = 137.02 AmountVat = 28.77 and Date = 2017-07-05, then return X. Otherwise nothing.

Comment: i have question each 4 row represent data that i should verify ? 

for exemple the first 4 row need to be verified and move on to the second 4 row and should be verify also correct me if i m wrong

Comment: If I understand you correctly, let me explain: 
Each of the rows represent a record. They all have the same X value. But i want to just receive X. So all the info needs to be present according to the query. So Record with name AmountGross needs to equal 123.45, the record with AmountNet needs to equal 137.02. AmountVat needs to equal 28.77. and the Date needs to equal 2017-07.05.

Only then return a X. If there is no match to all four of these records, no returned value

Comment: Each X has one of these values, if that makes sense. So X = 1, so one amountnet, one amountvat, one date, one amountgross to match X=1

Comment: i m not talking about the x i m talking about the records, that you have in your table are those data follow a pattern or not the condition is easy. but my problem is how many record do you have is it just 4 or 100 etc... because if the case you should solve your problem using cursors and i don't think there's an other solution in this case.

Comment: It can be 18 different options in the Name and Fieldinfo value varies always (but is filled with a variable). So the Amountvat is always Amountvat, only the value in FieldInfo varies.

does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
drop table if exists x;
create table x (xName  varchar(20), Fieldinfo numeric(10,2), ValueDateTime date, X int);
insert into x values
('Date'        , NULL      , '2017-07-05'  ,1),
('AmountGross' , 123.45    , NULL          ,1),
('AmountNet'   ,  137.02   , NULL          ,1),
('AmountVat'   , 28.77     , NULL          ,1);

SELECT x, count(*) as tel
from x where Fieldinfo in ('123.45', '137.02', '28.77') or
         valuedatetime =  '2017-07-05'
group by x.x
```

result

```
+------+-----+
| x    | tel |
+------+-----+
|    1 |   4 |
+------+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Maybe just create a temporary table to hold in all your data, so `create table #x`. I would recommend dropping any possibly persisted table, no matter how less likely the name of that table is.